# WebStorm JSON files unresolved variable properties (syntax)

Tags: json, node.js, webstorm

Practical example is this best here, so here goes. I have a JSON file named `file.json` as such:

```
{
    "key": "hello"
}
```

And a JS file in the same directory as such (NodeJS):

```
'use strict';

// Dependencies
const jsonFile = require('./file.json');

// Globals
const anotherFile = {
    key: 'world'
}

const fn = () => {
    console.log(jsonFile.key); // this 'key' is not recognized
    console.log(anotherFile.key); // this 'key' is recognized
};
```

Now, that `fn` function should, and does, print `hello` and `world` to the console. My problem is that while WebStorm recognizes the second file (`anotherFile`) as a JavaScript object, it doesn't do so with the one imported from the JSON.

That means that `anotherFile.key` has "`key`" in purple (in my template) color, while the other one is plain white with the underline that you get when it's "Unresolved variable key".
Also means that I can write `anotherFile` and it will show me all available options (functions, properties, etc) and `key` will be there, while in the first file, `jsonFile`, it wont.

Is there any way to force WebStorm to recognize JSON's as JavaScript objects? 
Thanks!

Edit: Using WebStorm 11.0.1

Comment: which version of webstorm are you using?

Comment: Version 11.0.1 currently. Adding to original topic.

Answer (score 1):

Please try upgrading - your code works fine for me in 2016.2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `Preference>Editor>File Types` you should have this :
But I thought it was like this by default ...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Don't have any JSON Schema, only JSON. But in an older version (11) of webstorm (vs 2016 current one).

Comment: and what are your patterns for JSON ?

Comment: `*.bowerrc`, `*.jsb2`, `*jsb3`, `*.json`